# Floating errors when using Trace

Tags: python, tkinter

I modified a piece of code that I found on here and for the most part it works, but warnings keep popping up. It's expecting floating-point number but got "" and I don't know why it's happening. I thought integers could be expressed as a floating number. The error goes away once the second number is entered for instance. if I just type "1" I get an warning, but as soon as I type "10" the warning stops popping up. It's kind of annoying because I have around 2000 lines of code and I need to be able to see real errors. [image]

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
def back(var1,var2):
    b=var1.get()+var2.get()
    print(var1.get())
    print(var2.get())
    a.set(b)


var1 = tk.DoubleVar()
var2 = tk.DoubleVar()
a=     tk.DoubleVar()

E1= tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var1)
E1.pack()
E2= tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var2)
E2.pack()
var1.trace('w',lambda name, index, mode, var1=var1: back(var1,var2))
var2.trace('w',lambda name, index, mode, var2=var2: back(var1,var2))
l=tk.Label(root, textvariable=a)
l.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `try`/`except` to catch and ignore the error.

Comment: When I run your code I don't get the error unless I delete everything in the widget. At that point I expect an error since you're unconditionally trying to convert an empty string to a floating point number.

Comment: this is so frustrating. I tried the try/except and it's not catching it either.  I guess I'll just have to comment this part out and write other parts of my code and once everything is checked, take the comment out.

Comment: How do you use try/except in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use `try / except` to catch the exception and do whatever you want in the `except` block:

```
def back(var1, var2):
    try:
        a.set(var1.get() + var2.get())
    except (ValueError, tk.TclError):
        # do whatever you want, or
        a.set('invalid value')
```